# Errors while trying to upgrade to the latest Unity3D (Game Engine) version

Tags: dpkg, unity3d

I had Unity 5.3.4f1 installed, but I wanted to upgrade to the latest version which is 2017.2.0f3 so I downloaded the .deb file from [here](http://beta.unity3d.com/download/ee86734cf592/unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb) then I tried to install it so I typed:

```
sudo dpkg -i unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb
```

which produced the following output after some time:

```
(Reading database ... 294886 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb ...
Unpacking unity-editor (2017.2.0f3) over (5.3.4f1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/jaxen-1.1.jar' to '/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/jaxen-1.1.jar.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb
```

Why is it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove Unity folder from `/opt/` and use `gdebi` to install the new version, which has proven far better than using `dpkg` and worrying about the dependencies. So simply do:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/Unity/
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb
```

Comment: I tried sudo gdebi unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb     ,but it said: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Failed to open the software package
The package might be corrupted or you are not allowed to open the file. Check the permissions of the file.

Comment: But did you remove the Unity directory in `/opt/`?

Comment: O.k. whats the output of `ls -l unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb` ? Might that the downloaded file is corrupted.

Comment: I did but luckly everything is solved now.  Something renamed the extention of the .deb file I downloaded to .deb1 so I installed that one(the .deb1) and it is unpacking now. :-)